# How to import tree-view-list-android into Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to import tree-view-list-android (https://github.com/Polidea/tree-view-list-android) into my Android studio project but having issues.

First I got a 'project.properties file missing' error which I fixed by adding the file.
Next I have 'java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration' errors which I haven't been able to fix.

Has anyone had any success importing this library into Android Studio (if so could you give me some guidance on how to do it) or know how to get this working?

I've tried lots of different things but so far had no luck.

Thanks for your help,
Oliver

Comment: That Gradle build file is for some pre-Android Studio approach to building... something. I recommend removing the library module from your project, getting a clean copy of the library's source, deleting the `build.gradle` file from that copy, then try the import-module wizard. Or, use a library that is newer, as this one hasn't been touched in years.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately neither of those methods worked but I did get it to work using another method. I created a new project then added all the source files and resource files from the tree-view-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I could get this to work was by creating a new project then adding the source files and resources from tree-view-list